# JEditorPane Hyperlink swing html

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

I'm having a difficult time getting the hyperlink to work in a JEditorPane. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I want to be able to click on the link and the browser to open to that page. Thanks in advance. :D

```
    bottomText.setText("<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo</a>");
    bottomText.setEditable(false);
    bottomText.setOpaque(false);
    bottomText.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
    bottomText.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {

            }
            if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that was simpler then I though :P

```
// Move this
//bottomText.setText("<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo</a>");
bottomText.setEditable(false);
bottomText.setOpaque(false);
bottomText.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"))
// To Here
bottomText.setText("<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo</a>");
```

Oh, and wait till the user has clicked the link before opening the browser, had about 4 windows going before I killed your example ;)

**UPDATE with Click**

You were almost there ;)

```
bottomText.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I do that? I've just started learning Java so I'm not very experienced. Thanks to both of you for your help!

Comment: Thanks again sir! How would I go about changing the font of the JEditorPane text? I don't like how it looks now so I would like to change to the default Arial text. Thanks again!

Comment: @HenryPe change the font via HTML

Answer (score 3):

call `bottomText.setEditorKit` before `bottomText.setText`

Comment: Thank you sir, how can I vote up / accept answers to both of you? It won't let me accept both answers or at least vote it up.