# Displaying HTML in Swing, is my example not working?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, browser

I copied the code from this [tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-create-simple-swing-html-viewer-browser-java) and everything works as expected except the hyperlink does nothing after a mouse click. My mouse arrow changes from an arrow to a hand on mouse over, but I expected a browser to be launched. Is this correct behavior? Do I have to add something else to have it launch in a browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753042/jeditorpane-hyperlink-swing-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't add a `HyperLinkListener` to the editor pane. Read the `JEditorPane` API for an example on how to do this. While reading the API don't forget to click on the `Using Text Components` link for a more detailed example.

The Swing tutorial is the place to start for the basics.