# How can i add JLabel and JTextArea in the same space in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jtextarea

Here is the UI that I'd like to make.

[image]

I'm new to UI design. Could anyone tell me which layout should i use? How to make JLabel and JTextArea stick together and make String in the JTextArea clickable? Are there better ways to realize this design.
I have tried BorderLayout, but it seems that I can not add JLabel and JTextArea together into same spot.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Can we see your code? I'm not sure which part of the picture you are talking about. Do you mean the very top?

Comment: *"Could anyone tell me which layout should i use?"*  Rarely does a GUI use just a single layout.  Typically we 'divide and conquer' a GUI - using whatever layout for each part that best suits it.  Having said that, I'd probably use a single `GridBagLayout` for that GUI.

Comment: I see `GridBagLayout` mostly, but what I think you really want to know is, how to use a `TitledBorder`, see [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: I see more than one question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a complex UI would be made up a series of compound components and layouts, each focusing on a particular area of responsibility.  This makes life much easier, as you focus on a small area without been worried about how it might affect unrelated elements.

Having said that, I think what you really want is a `TitledBorder`, for example...

[image: Border]

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 20);
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
wrapper.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Details"));
wrapper.add(sp);
```

This will greatly simplify your layout, as you simply need to layout the `wrapper` panel and not the label AND associated component.

The drawback here is you do lose the keyboard shortcut functionality that `JLabel` can provide, but you can use the same idea (of a wrapper component) to wrap a `JLabel` and associated component into a easy to use package.

Depending on the route you take, I'd see `GridBagLayout` and possible `BorderLayout` and `FlowLayout` coming into play.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

> String in the JTextArea clickable

That's rather complex at best.  If you mean like a hyperlink, then I'd recommending doing some research into a `JEditorPane`, it will make it (somewhat) easier

Something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753042/jeditorpane-hyperlink-swing-html)

Comment: Thanks alot to your comment. In my example, there are 5 classe names under classe border , how to make that if i click on a class name, it shows attributs's name in the attribut border? Suppose attribut names are already in a String[].

Comment: [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: for each textArea, I have to create a specific JPanel with TitledBorder to contain it?

Comment: It would provide the best look, cause otherwise you'd be modifying the border of the scroll pane, which might look weird

Comment: It seems that I should use JList instead JTextArea, so I have to set panel size first and add JList dynamically?

Comment: You can affect the size of a `JList` by using `setVisibleRowCount` - Remember, things render differently on different systems, best to avoid absolute size values

Comment: after i replace JTextArea by JList, since JList is empty at beginning, the panels are wrapped together. Is there a way to create a white panel like your image above but with JList, not JTextArea.